# Python: how to separate time records(e.g. 2015-02-01 12:34:22) in to two different arrays

Tags: python, pandas

The `dataframe` is as follows:

```
1       2015-02-01 18:04:33
2       2015-02-01 12:28:15
3       2015-02-01 12:28:56
4       2015-02-01 00:45:08
5       2015-02-01 00:46:28
6       2015-02-01 00:59:56
7       2015-02-01 01:00:21
8       2015-02-01 01:00:21
9       2015-02-01 01:02:51
10      2015-02-01 01:02:51
11      2015-02-01 01:14:14
```

These time records(e.g. 2015-02-01 01:02:51)are treated as a single array in this data frame, and I want to separate it into data and hour, e.g. 2015-02-01 is in a array, and 01:00:21 is in another array.

df.info() shows Int64Index: 695366 entries, 0 to 695365 Data columns (total 13 columns): URID 695366 non-null object GPRS 632202 non-null object datetime 695362 non-null object

I tried using `split`
in `numpy`, but it did not work. So I wonder whether there is other ways to work it out?

Comment: What error are you getting when you use `split`? can you post code snippet?  Is it a `Panda Dataframe` or a `file input` or just a `list`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `dtype` is `datetime` then you can use [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor to separate the column:

```
In [32]:
df['date'], df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.date, df['datetime'].dt.time
df

Out[32]:
                 datetime        date      time
index                                          
1     2015-02-01 18:04:33  2015-02-01  18:04:33
2     2015-02-01 12:28:15  2015-02-01  12:28:15
3     2015-02-01 12:28:56  2015-02-01  12:28:56
4     2015-02-01 00:45:08  2015-02-01  00:45:08
5     2015-02-01 00:46:28  2015-02-01  00:46:28
6     2015-02-01 00:59:56  2015-02-01  00:59:56
7     2015-02-01 01:00:21  2015-02-01  01:00:21
8     2015-02-01 01:00:21  2015-02-01  01:00:21
9     2015-02-01 01:02:51  2015-02-01  01:02:51
10    2015-02-01 01:02:51  2015-02-01  01:02:51
11    2015-02-01 01:14:14  2015-02-01  01:14:14
```

Comment: No, it's not datetime, it's dataframe, How to transfer it to datetime type?

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: no, it is a file input data. But I also use pd.DataFrame on it.

Comment: So you're not using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library? You can load this using `read_csv` and pass `parse_dates=True` and it will convert the data into datetime

Comment: Oh you mean pandas library, yes , I use read_csv to read data.

Comment: So what are the `dtypes`? what does `df.info()` show?

Comment: The code is    `df=pd.read_csv('sessions20150201.txt',names=['URID','APPNAME','APPID','AppType','GPRS','datetime'],na_values=['NULL'],parse_dates=True)` and the `dtype` of `df['datetime']` is `object`object.

Comment: Try passing `parse_dates=['datetime']` or after loading `df['datetim'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`

Comment: `df.info()` shows`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`
`Int64Index: 695366 entries, 0 to 695365`
`Data columns (total 13 columns):`
`URID       695366 non-null object`
`GPRS       632202 non-null object`
`datetime     695362 non-null object`

Comment: Please edit this into your question, the formatting get lost in comments, also did you try what I suggested?